# Django ManyToMany relation to 'self' without backward relations

Tags: django, orm, django-related-manager

There are several question about backwards relations here, but I'm either too dumb to understand them or think they don't fit my case.

I have model

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    stuff = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = 'combined+')
```

I have created form where i combine the information stored. And it stores object relations in database like that:

Table:

```
id:from_stuff_id:to_stuff_id
1:original_object_id:first_related_object
2:original_object_id:second_related_object
3:first_related_object:original_object_id
4:second_related_object:original_object_id
```

So when i display object first_related_object and check for relations with

```
myobject.stuff.all()
```

Then i get the "original_object". But i do not need it. I wish it would show no backwards relation like that.

Edit1

So i suck at explaining myself.

Perhaps this code will better illustrate what i want.

```
myobjectone = MyModel.objects.get(pk = 1)
myobjecttwo = MyModel.objects.get(pk = 2)
myobjectthree = MyModel.objects.get(pk = 3)
myobjectone.stuff.add(myobjecttwo)
myobjectone.stuff.add(myobjectthree)
myobjectone.stuff.all()
[myobjecttwo, myobjectthree] <-- this i want
myobjecttwo.stuff.all()
[myobjectone]<-- this i do not want
myobjectthree.stuff.all()
[myobjectone]<-- this i do not want
```

Now only question is - if i should even use stuff.all() if i dont want the results they yield and should write my own manager/methods to get list of objects which excludes backward relations.

/edit1

edit2
In response to Henry Florence:

Okay - i did test it with empty base and it looks like symmetrical = False does have database level differences. I think.

I created empty table with symmetrical = False, then creating adding relations did not spawn backwards relations. If i created empty table without symmetrical = False. Then they were. Setting symmetrical = False makes no difference AFTER tables have been created. So i guess the differences are on database level.

/edit2
So what am i supposed to do here?

Write my own manager or something?

Alan

Comment: Do you mean excluding the current object from the results, like `myobject.stuff.exclude(id=self.id)`?

Comment: Nope. i mean excluding 3rd and 4th row in table from results when queried with myobject.stuff.all(), myobject beeing the first_related_object. I dont want the original_object to show from other objects .all() queries.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think you might be looking for the [`symmetrical`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) option. Try setting `symmetrical=False`.

Comment: Yeah i know - i suck at explaining. Symmetrical might do some of the work, but i'm not seeing desired results.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that the ManyToMany relationship should be one way, in that if the following is true:

```
             --------------           ----------------
             | mymodelone |---------->|  mymodeltwo  |
             --------------     |     ----------------
                                |
                                |     ----------------
                                ----->| mymodelthree |
                                      ----------------
```

Then there should not be an implicit relationship in the other direction:

```
             --------------           ----------------
             | mymodelone |<-----/----|  mymodeltwo  |
             --------------           ----------------

             --------------           ----------------
             | mymodelone |<-----/----| mymodelthree |
             --------------           ----------------
```

`ManyToMany` fields have a `symmetrical` property which by default is `True`, see: [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical).

To create a new app to demonstrate the non symmetric ManyToMany field:

Create a new app:

```
$ python ./manage.py startapp stuff
```

Add stuff app in `settings.py`:

```
...
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'stuff'
)
....
```

edit `stuff/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    stuff = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = 'combined+', symmetrical=False, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = "description")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "MyModel%i" % self.id
```

Sync the db:

```
$ python ./manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Creating table stuff_mymodel_stuff
Creating table stuff_mymodel
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

and then test in the django shell:

```
$ python ./manage.py shell
>>> from stuff.models import MyModel
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel1>, <MyModel: MyModel2>, <MyModel: MyModel3>]
>>> m1 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> m2 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=2)
>>> m3 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=3)
>>> m1.stuff.all()
[]
>>> m1.stuff.add(m2)
>>> m1.stuff.add(m3)
>>> m1.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel2>, <MyModel: MyModel3>]
>>> m2.stuff.all()
[]
>>> m3.stuff.all()
[]
>>>
```

**Edit - ManyToMany relationship on existing models**

The symmetry of the `ManyToManyField` is created when the models are written to the database, rather than when they are read. If we alter the model to:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    stuff = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = 'combined+')

def __unicode__(self):
    return "MyModel%i" % self.id
```

Create new `MyModel` instances:

```
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel1>, <MyModel: MyModel2>, <MyModel: MyModel3>, <MyModel: MyModel4>, <MyModel: MyModel5>]
>>> m4 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=4)
>>> m5 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=5)
>>> m4.stuff.add(m5)
>>> m4.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel5>]
>>> m5.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel4>]
```

As expected the stuff `ManyToManyField` is creating symmetrical relations. If we then set the `ManyToManyField` to `symmetrical = False`:

```
>>> from stuff.models import MyModel
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel().save()
>>> MyModel.objects.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel1>, <MyModel: MyModel2>, <MyModel: MyModel3>, <MyModel: MyModel4>, <MyModel: MyModel5>, <MyModel: MyModel6>, <MyModel: MyModel7>]
>>> m6 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=6)
>>> m7 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=7)
>>> m6.stuff.all()
[]
>>> m7.stuff.all()
[]
>>> m6.stuff.add(m7)
>>> m6.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel7>]
>>> m7.stuff.all()
[]
>>> m5 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=5)
>>> m4 = MyModel.objects.get(pk=4)
>>> m4.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel5>]
>>> m5.stuff.all()
[<MyModel: MyModel4>]
```

It can be seen the new `ManyToMany` relation between `m6` and `m7` is not symmetrical, however the existing one, between `m4` and `m5` is still symmetrical as the model stated when those objects were created.

**Edit - additional database constraints with a symmetrical foreign key**

Apologies to the reader to the length of this answer, we seem to be exploring this problem at some depth.

In sql a many to many relation is modeled by creating a table that holds all the information unique to the relation - usually just the primary key value of the two tables.

So for our `MyModel`, django creates two tables:

```
             -----------------           -----------------------
             | stuff_mymodel |---------->| stuff_mymodel_stuff |
             -----------------           -----------------------
                      ^                              |
                      |                              |
                      --------------------------------
```

The links shown in the diagram are represented by primary key or id values within the schema:

```
mysql> describe stuff_mymodel;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe stuff_mymodel_stuff;
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_mymodel_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| to_mymodel_id   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And shown as the output from the Django `manage.py` script:

```
$ python ./manage.py sql stuff
    BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE `stuff_mymodel_stuff` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `from_mymodel_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `to_mymodel_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`from_mymodel_id`, `to_mymodel_id`)
)
;
CREATE TABLE `stuff_mymodel` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
;
ALTER TABLE `stuff_mymodel_stuff` ADD CONSTRAINT `from_mymodel_id_refs_id_7fa00238` FOREIGN KEY (`from_mymodel_id`) REFERENCES `stuff_mymodel` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `stuff_mymodel_stuff` ADD CONSTRAINT `to_mymodel_id_refs_id_7fa00238` FOREIGN KEY (`to_mymodel_id`) REFERENCES `stuff_mymodel` (`id`);
COMMIT;
```

This sql is the same irrespective if the django `ManyToManyField` is symmetrical or not. The only difference is the number of rows created in the `stuff_mymodel_stuff` table:

```
mysql> select * from stuff_mymodel_stuff;
+----+-----------------+---------------+
| id | from_mymodel_id | to_mymodel_id |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
|  1 |               1 |             2 |
|  2 |               1 |             3 |
|  3 |               4 |             5 |
|  4 |               5 |             4 |
|  5 |               6 |             7 |
+----+-----------------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The link `m4 -> m5` being symmetrical and the others not. Digging around in the Django source we can find the code responsible for creating the 'mirror' entry in the sql, if `symmetrical` is `True`:

```
    # If the ManyToMany relation has an intermediary model,
    # the add and remove methods do not exist.
    if rel.through._meta.auto_created:
        def add(self, *objs):
            self._add_items(self.source_field_name, self.target_field_name, *objs)

            # If this is a symmetrical m2m relation to self, add the mirror entry in the m2m table
            if self.symmetrical:
                self._add_items(self.target_field_name, self.source_field_name, *objs)
        add.alters_data = True
```

This is currently line 605 on github: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py

Hope this answers all your queries.

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for, but this is not what i see, when i do the same thing you described. And i have this field declared like this : stuff = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name = 'combined+', symmetrical=False, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name = _(u"description"))

Comment: why is the string for verbose_name in your comment written like that? It throws an error for me. I had to create and persist new MyModels to get the code above to work, are there stale versions in your db?

Comment: verbose_name is just from the real model not the simple example i used to illustrate problem here. And yes - i have not touched database since the model changes, because i read somewhere that these related_name and symmetrical changes do not need to touch database anyway. Was i wrong?

Comment: and in fact it seems they don't hit the database cause: python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: ah ok, I've edited my post to show how to create the model in a new app and demonstrate creating a non symmetric relation, this definitely works in Django 1.4-1.6, I copied the shell output from the shell. Alternatively, can you post / link to more of your code, I would be happy to debug it.

Comment: In all important matters - my code looks EXACTLY like yours. I also use django 1.4. Only difference is that i use django-south to migrate the stuff. From the tables that syncdb creates for your case i guess that i got exactly the same tables. I even desribed the columns and values which you get in stuff_mymodel_stuff in my original post (id:from_stuff_id:to_stuff_id). The fact is though - when i run the commands you do, in shell, then they work as i describe, not as you describe. Like i said - the symmetrical or related_name make no difference in database.

Comment: Can you try running the commands in the post to create a new app called stuff to simply test the code on your machine? Otherwise, post more of your app and I will be happy to help you debug it.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb I agree - an issue with South or the database structure would seem very unlikely. Are you creating new objects to test the `ManyToMany` relation? See the edit in my post above.

Comment: I'll try it later today. Other stuff is keeping me busy right now.

Comment: Allright. I tested it and it seems you are right. If table is created with symmetrical = False set, then the backwards relations are not created. Setting/removing symmetrical = False after tables have been created makes no difference. See Edit2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40971/discussion-between-henry-florence-and-odif-yltsaeb)

Comment: allright. I checked out what kind of differences are there on database level and there are several additional constraints added to tables when manytomany field is defined with symmetrical = False. I'm sure if you open your database and see how tables were created (export as sql), then you get the information too. Just add it to your answer and ill accept it.