# Django: query many2many self referenced

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Currently I have this models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)

    dependency = models.ManyToManyField('self',related_name='group_rel')
    name = models.TextField()


class Publication(models.Model):

    name = models.TextField()
    group = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='group_dependency')
```

I can get all fathers(groups) for one group.

```
group = Group.objects.filter(pk=1)[0]
group.dependency.all()
```

But I want to query all childrens(groups) for one group.

```
dir(group)
```

> ['DoesNotExist', 'MultipleObjectsReturned', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**setstate**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_check_column_name_clashes', '_check_field_name_clashes', '_check_fields', '_check_id_field', '_check_index_together', '_check_local_fields', '_check_long_column_names', '_check_m2m_through_same_relationship', '_check_managers', '_check_model', '_check_model_name_db_lookup_clashes', '_check_ordering', '_check_swappable', '_check_unique_together', '_do_insert', '_do_update', '_get_FIELD_display', '_get_next_or_previous_by_FIELD', '_get_next_or_previous_in_order', '_get_pk_val', '_get_unique_checks', '_meta', '_perform_date_checks', '_perform_unique_checks', '_save_parents', '_save_table', '_set_pk_val', '_state', 'check', 'clean', 'clean_fields', 'date_error_message', 'delete', 'dependency', 'from_db', 'full_clean', 'get_deferred_fields', 'group_dependency', 'id', 'name', 'objects', 'pk', 'prepare_database_save', 'refresh_from_db', 'save', 'save_base', 'seri    alizable_value', 'unique_error_message', 'validate_unique']

Note: Publication is this question is not used. I only show it because there are a many2many to group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django ManyToMany relation to 'self' without backward relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837728/django-manytomany-relation-to-self-without-backward-relations)

Comment: Correct! Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

You've named the many-to-many field `dependency`, so that's what you should use.

```
group.dependency.all()
```

Comment: Thanks to reply, but this it returned all father of this group, not all childrens of this group.

Comment: It's not clear what you are treating as parent and child here. But if you want the reverse, then use the related name: `group.group_rel.all()`.

Comment: Yep can be not clear what I am treating as parent and child, my mistake. I tried with `group.group_rel.all()` but group don't have attribute `group_rel`

`AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'group_rel'`